# Question related to order of groups

Tags: group-theory

Given $A$ is a subset of grouo $G$ and $|A|>|\frac{G}{2}|$. How do i prove that each element  of $G$ is product of rwo elements of $A$? I don't know where to begin, a hint would be very helpful.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: If $A$ is any subset of $G$, show that $g\in G$ is a product of two elements of $A$ if and only if
$$
  A\cap\{a^{-1}g\mid a\in A\}\neq\emptyset.
$$